# Android VR View: Converting mono 360 photo

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have a Mono 360 photo which uses a single pano and I need a Stereo 360 photo which uses two stacked panos.

**My question:**

Is there any way to convert it in my app with a few lines of Code?

Here is a usefull link which describes the Problem:
https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview

**For example:**

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to do this in the ImageLoaderTask Class to use 2:1 images:

```
 panoOptions = new Options();
 panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;
```

instead of :

```
panoOptions = new Options();
panoOptions.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
```